# Assigning to 'node *' from incompatible type 'void'

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am implementing a pre-Order Traversal function. But I am stuck at pop() function. It keeps giving this error " Assigning to 'node *' from incompatible type 'void' "  . I have tried this with node* instead of void function but this one keeps giving an error.

not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
  int data;
  node *left;
  node *right;

  node(int d) {
    this->data = d;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
  }
};

void preOrderTraversalR(node *root) {
  if (root) {
    cout << root->data << " ";
    preOrderTraversalR(root->left);
    preOrderTraversalR(root->right);
  }
}

node* preOrderTraversalS(node *root){
    stack<node*> S;
    while(1){
        while(root){
            cout<<root->data;
            S.push(root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        if(S.empty()) break;
        root = S.pop();
        root=root->right;
    }
}

node *createTree(node *root) {
  int val;
  cout << "Enter Node: ";
  cin >> val;

  root = new node(val);

  if (val == -1) {
    return NULL;
  }
  cout << "Enter node left of " << val << " : ";
  root->left = createTree(root->left);
  cout << "Enter node right of " << val << " : ";
  root->right = createTree(root->right);

  return root;
}

// 8 3 1 -1 -1 6 4 -1 -1 7 -1 -1 10 -1 14 13 -1 -1
int main() {
  node *root = NULL;
  root = createTree(root);

  cout << "\n";
  preOrderTraversalR(root);
}
```

Comment: `S.pop()` has a return type of `void`.  What do you expect `root = S.pop();` to do?

Comment: Swap `S.pop()` for [`S.top()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/top/) e.g. Get the top `node` on the stack with `top()` and then `pop()` from the stack

Comment: Side note use `nullptr` not `NULL` and move your root inside a list class, a list should hide its internal nodes. The whole idea of classes is you can protect the handling of the internal data. With a list using code should be able to find, append, insert and remove data (without having to know about the internal nodes at all). Have a look at the interface for [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you encountered is because you used `S.pop()` incorrectly (At least, I think so. Correct me if that was intended). The `pop()` method for the stack container in C++ does not return the popped element, it simply removes the top element from the stack. To fix this, you should change `S.pop()` to `S.top()` to access the top element of the stack and then use `S.pop()` to remove it.

Otherwise, you would simply remove the top element from the stack and assign `void` value to the `root` pointer. (that is what's happening here)

```
node* preOrderTraversalS(node *root){
    stack<node*> S;
    while(1){
        while(root){
            cout << root->data << " ";
            S.push(root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        if(S.empty()) break;
        root = S.top();      // Access the top element of the stack
        S.pop();             // Remove the top element from the stack
        root = root->right;
    }
    return nullptr;          // You should also return something here, perhaps nullptr or else change it to void() function
}
```

I hope it helps.

Also, it seems that there may be an issue with the input mechanism, resulting in an indefinite prompt for node input. Feel free to reach out if you require any assistance or further clarification.